# Take input from a column of one file, and match a condition in two columns in second file

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, grep

I have two files like this:

File 1:

```
1   1987969 1987970 .   7.078307    33
1   2066715 2066716 .   7.426998    34
1   2066774 2066775 .   6.851217    33
```

File 2:

```
1   HANASAI gelliu  1186928 1441229
1   FEBRUCA sepaca  3455487 3608150
```

I want to take each value of column 3 in File 1, and search in File 2 with a condition like (`if File1_col3_value >= File2_col4_value && File1_col3_value <= File2_col5_value`) then print the whole line of File 2 in a new file.

One more thing is also important: for every variable from file_1 to be searched in file_2, the corresponding value in column_1 should be the same in both files, e.g. for '1987970' of file_1, the value in corresponding in column_1 is '1', so in file_2, it should also be '1' in first column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Only considers lines with matching "class" values in column 1

```
$ cat msh.awk
# Save all the pairs of class and third-column values from file1
NR==FNR { a[$1,$3]; next }

# For each line of file2, if there exists a third-column-file1
# value between the values of columns 4 and 5 in a record of the
# same class, print the line
{
    for (cv in a) {
        split(cv, class_val, SUBSEP);
        c = class_val[1];
        v = class_val[2];
        if (c == $1 && v >= $4 && v <= $5) {
            print
            break
        }
    }
}

$ cat file1
1   1987969 1987970 .   7.078307    33
1   2066715 2066716 .   7.426998    34
1   2066774 1200000 .   6.851217    33
1   2066774 2066775 .   6.851217    33

$ cat file2
1   HANASAI gelliu  1186928 1441229
1   FEBRUCA sepaca  3455487 3608150

$ awk -f msh.awk file1 file2
1   HANASAI gelliu  1186928 1441229
```

Comment: thank you, I used the command in one line as:

awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3]; next}{for (v in a) {if (v >= $4 && v <= $5) {print}}}' file_1 file_2

this worked for me, but there are two issues:

1. I got some output lines which even dont meet the condition, (v >= $4 && v <= $5), I dont know why these are here.

2. The first column of both the files is a class. There are 20 classed in each file. So, is it possible that the variable 'v' is searched in the same class of file_2...i.e both class 1 in this case. 

Can you please address these...

Comment: Edit your question to have sample data for each of the input files with the exact output you expect from that input, making sure to include data that demonstrates the cases that are failing with this solution. Also, there's nothing about "classes" or anything to do with the first column of either file in your question, so if that's important information that needs to be added to the requirements, please do so.

Comment: can you address the 2nd paragraph of the question, i have edited it.

Comment: Edited with new version that makes sure the column 1 values match.